# Google play Store shows your device isn't compatible with this version <Android os 12>

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, android-manifest, android-12

i have android application which i can run from android studio on my android device (os 12), but after publishing it to google play store it shows that my device isn't compatible with this version of the app

and i specified below

targetSdkVersion 31
minSdkVersion 19

and below my manifiest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <queries>
        <!-- Specific intents you query for -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>

    <application
        android:name=".base.BaseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="q">
        <activity
```

if you know the reason please help

i did search on this problem and all i found was to clear the cash and data for play store but it didn't workout, the problem still exist, i really want to know how to fix this issue

Comment: Looks like you’re filtering out large screens.

Comment: i added the large screen but still the same problem appeared, even when i search the app on play store i can't find it

Comment: Your update got approved that fast?!!!

Comment: yes it approved because it's not the first upload to the the app

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are using <compatible-screens> tag with specific device screen configurations? If not, I would drop it completely and reupload.